# Help In code template

Tags: c++

Given this code

```
template <typename T>
typename T::ElementT at (T const &a , T const &b)
{
        return a[i] ;
}
```

what do

```
typename T::ElementT
```

and

```
a[i]
```

mean?

Comment: May I ask where you got this piece of code from? It seems quite useless? And did it have those errors (I think it should be `const typename T::ElementT`, and what's with `b` vs. `i`?) or did you put them in?

Answer (score 3):

```
typename T::ElementT
```

Since `T:ElementT` is a dependent name, that is why you see the keyword `typename` before it. It tells the compiler that `ElementT` is a tested *type*, **not** *value*.

And as for `a[i]`, it seems that `T` is a class that has defined `operator[]` which is being called when you write `a[i]`. For example, `T` could be `sample` as (partially) defined here:

```
class sample
{
 public:
      typedef int ElementT; //nested type!

      //...

      ElementT operator[](int i) 
      {
          return m_data[i];
      }

      ElementT *m_data;
      //...
};
```

Now, if `T` is `sample`, then you can write `T::ElementT` as well as `a[i]` which is of *type* `T`.  In this case when `T` is sample, I'm assuming that the *type* of index `i` is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

i guess in that code T is always a class which has operator [] overloaded and has a subclass defenition ElementT any other class which doesn't have these two qualities will make an error while compile.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> typename T::ElementT
> ```

This is explained exhaustingly by Johannes in [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names) to the C++ FAQ.

> ```
> a[i]
> ```

This operation is usually called "subscription" and accesses the i-th element in `a`. In order to do that, `a` must either be an array or some class that overloads the subscription operator (like `std::vector` or `std::map`).
However, as Nawaz pointed out in his comment, since `a` is of type `T`, and since `T` is expected to have a nested type `ElementAt`, in this case `a` cannot be an array.

Comment: in this case, `a` cannot be an array, because the type of `a` is `T` which has a nested type!